# Exporting CGridView data to Csv - Yii Framework

Tags: yii, yii-extensions

How to export CGridView data to Csv format? I am not able to understand this extension.

```
http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/eexcel
```

Accessing to the above URL throws the below error:

```
Error
Unable to find the requested extension.
```

Answer (score 2):

Hope this would help you

[CSV EXPORT](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/csvexport)